# Adding a new entry to a Access table

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm very new to programing and am trying to link a database to a website. I want the website to allow a user to make a username (`OrgID`) and password (`OrgPassword`) and have them apear in my database table (`Organizer`). This is the code I have so far, but I cannot get it to update the information in the database. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
protected void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

  if (txtUserName.Text != "" && OrgPassword.Text !="")
  {
    string cnnString = "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =C:/Users/codym/Desktop/Fall 2011/Information Systems/Project/CampuSpaceDatabase2.accdb";
    OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(cnnString);

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    string cmdText= "SELECT * FROM Organizer";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, cnx);
    adapter.SelectCommand= cmd;
    adapter.Fill(Organizer);
    Session["Organizer"]= Organizer;
    Organizer= ((DataTable)Session["Organizer"]);
    string orgname = OrgID.Text;
    string orgpass = OrgPassword.Text;
    foreach (DataRow in Organizer.Rows)
    {
      if(row["OrgID"].ToString() == orgname & row["OrgPassword"].ToString() == orgpass)
      {
        errLabel.Text = "Welcome "+ row["OrgID"].ToString();
        return;
      }
      else
      {
        errLabel.Text = "OrgID/Password Invalid";
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing opening the connection:

```
OleDbConnection cnx = new OleDbConnection(cnnString);
cnx.Open();
```